# bootstrap accordion menus pinned to bottom- menu height of tallest moves other menus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

```
<!--        Bottom Row-->
<div class="bottom-row">
    <!--First Accordion-->
    <div class="panel-group col-xs-6" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading gold" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle">
                            first one
                        </a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Stuff</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading gold">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle">
                            Stuff3
                        </a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>More stuff</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading gold">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseThree">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle">
                            Even more stuff
                        </a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Stuff99</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading blue">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseFour">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle">
4th entry
                        </a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Other stuff</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of first accordion-->






    <!--            Start of second accordion-->
    <div class="panel-group col-xs-6" id="accordion2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading gold" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#collapseOne2">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle">
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>VHS.</li>
                        <li>VHS.</li>
                        <li>VHS.</li>
                        <li>VHS.</li>
                        <li>VHS.</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#collapseTwo2">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle">
                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                        </a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#collapseThree2">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle">
                        Collapsible#3
                        </a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--            End of second Accordion-->





</div>
<!-- /.bottom-row -->
```

and the CSS:
    .bottom-row {
        bottom: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }

Trying to Bootstrap a previous site and mimic its functionality, but having an issue. 
When trying to pin a row of accordion menus to the bottom of the page, each menu floats to the top of the tallest menu on loading and shifts position when another menu changes height.

I would like the bottom of each menu to stay there regardless of what its neighbors are doing.  If I try and pin them to the bottom individually, they don't seem to find the bottom.

If sticky footer is the answer, I'm not sure how to implement it.

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/CarnivorousRex/whzgw1rk/

Comment: Why are you use absolute position? Any reason?

Comment: Fixed and absolute seem to have the same behavior.  Any other way I should be doing it?